# Ruby on rails: I need to render a View with data from two unrelated Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a Student View with Student Details. But in the same view,  I need to add a collection_select which will be populated with values from another model Hobbies (which is a separated, unrelated model)

Now my question is how do I access the Hobbies Model in the Student/id/new view?

Can I use fields_for to do this. If yes, then how?

Comment: You can do something like this @hobbies =  Hobby.all in your controller method. new or edit. than you can access all hobbies in your form . your another question. for fields for, can you post association of student and student details here ?

Comment: @DanilSperansky: Yes. For that I have another model student_hobbies

Comment: @Vishal: I am doing that. but how do I access it in the form?

Comment: @Anukrity You can access it with variable @hobbies. `<%= f.select :hobby_id,
         options_for_select(@hobbies.collect{|e| [e.name , e.id]}  ) %>` . it is just example. please don't consider as solution

Comment: Thank you vishal for your prompt replies. It was a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All models and controller instance variables are accessible in views. So you could do:

```
# in view
<%= f.collection_select :hobbie_ids, Hobbie.all, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true %>
```

Or you could do:

```
# in controller
@hobbies = Hobbie.all
# in view
<%= f.collection_select :hobbie_ids, @hobbies, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true %>
```

The code above is written in an assumption you have `has_and_belongs_to_many :hobbies` relationship.

Comment: Thank you Danil. Yes this worked. Though I decided to use the Chosen gem for the collection_select for a better look and feel.